# Identify a book and sequel about Mattias Hand, inventor and Prince who is exiled

Tags: story-identification, books

I once read a book where the main character was named Mattias. I believe his surname was Hand, or Han, but cannot be absolutely sure. Mattias was son of the king of the northern kingdom on the planet, and was inclined to play with Technology even though it was against the law. The kings wife (Mattias' step mother) came up with a plan to discredit Mattias and he was exiled, making her son next in line for the throne.

Mattias escapes to the island of Orleans, between the northern and southern continents, where he meets Momo (?) and starts a band. Eventually Orleans gets invaded by the southern continent and Mattias travels to their capital city where he joins a group of scientists trying to regain knowledge they've lost over the years.

The end of the book is basically when Mattias builds a radio to get in contact with a space station orbiting the planet, and they're told that there's a new spaceship from Earth approaching.

The second book (which I believe is called Corporation One, after the spaceship approaching) follows on.

I cannot remember the author nor the title. Can anyone help?

Comment: Might it be **The Royal Elite: Mattias** by Danielle Bourdon?

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18857352-mattias

It involves a Prince and its certainly not 'mediaeval fiction' but unfortunately it seems a rather low-key book and I can't find anymore information on it or a sample to check the other facts .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is definitely not it.

Comment: @mac While you may not have had the answer, your suggestion did jog my memory somewhat and I was able to find it! Thank you so much! The book I was looking for was/is called [Expatria by Keith Brooke](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10050945-expatria).

Comment: haha nicely done! Glad I could help :P only took two and a half years to find, I hope its a REALLY good book ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is called *Expatria* by Keith Brooke ([GoodReads Link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10050945-expatria)). The sequel is called *Expatria Incorporated*.

> The descendants of Expatria's first colonists from Earth have rejected technology. When **Mathias Hanrahan,** heir to the primacy of Newest Delhi, wants to reintroduce the old ways he is framed for his father's murder and forced to flee.
>
> Recruited by a research team which is trying to relearn the ancient technologies, he goes to work for them, and against a background of impending war, Mathias discovers that strange messages are coming from space.

Thanks to @MacCooper for jogging my memory a bit more!

Comment: Good job finding the book! Please don't forget to *accept* your own answer (click the checkmark on the left) so that this question is marked as solved :-)